# Git push not responding, after Formating pc

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-clone

I uploaded my proects to github and then i foramted my pc. after that when i wanted to get my projects back on my pc then i did git clone after oing that i started working on my project again, once i was done i then tried to commit the changes and push the code to the github but its stuck on this [gitbash screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHEu1.png)
and when i try to close git bash this pops up [pop up screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juGsv.png) and when i try to run \cmd in git bash and then i close the gitbash then also it shows this pop up screen shot [pop up screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juGsv.png)

Comment: Check if the issue persists with the latest Git For Windows snapshot: https://wingit.blob.core.windows.net/files/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try providing

> git remote add origin1

or (word other than origin) instead of git remote add origin command
and then again try (Simply replace origin with origin1 in the command you've used ,keep other things in the commands  same as previous)

And then ,

> git push -u origin1 master

Comment: tried it but still the same is happening

Comment: did you try replacing any other word instead of origin?

Comment: yes i did but still the same problem is happening